# Is sun revolving around certain mass in space with reference to some other galaxy?

Tags: astronomy, orbital-motion, sun, rotation

Every planet and satellite revolves around their mother planet and about their own axis as we know. So they are compacted as a system. Then why not sun?

Comment: The sun orbits the [supermassive black hole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagittarius_A*) in the core of the galaxy.

Comment: I guessed so.Please sir,Can you tell me is this answer 'supermassive blackhole'is the name given to unknown body?The body may be another sun to another galaxy?

Comment: The text "supermassive black hole" links to the Wikipedia article on Sagittarius A$^*$, our particular black hole. You may want to read the article [about black holes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole), as explaining *what* it is will take more space than I have in the comment box.

Comment: @dipendra no, a supermassive black hole is a black hole (a known entity in its own right) that is much more massive than your ordinary, uninteresting black holes

Comment: @Jim: I whole-heartedly disagree that "ordinary" black holes are "uninteresting."

Comment: @KyleKanos 1) I was being facetious 2) "uninteresting" is a relative term and I was comparing them to supermassive black holes, which I think you can agree are more interesting. And 3) have you ever actually *met* a low mass black hole? They are incredibly boring; no conversation skills or sense of humour whatsoever. Definitely uninteresting.

Comment: @Jim Plus, they tend to crush you once you get close to them. I wouldn't recommend getting very social :/

Comment: @dipendra: to be pedantic, the sun revolves around the center of mass of the galaxy, which is governed more by the other stars in the galaxy than by the SMBH at the glactic core.  It is not a completely analogous case to that of the sun -- the sun accounts for more than 99% of the mass of the solar system, while the SMBH at the galactic core is something like 1/500 of the mass of the galaxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Sun and our whole Solar System are revolving around the centre of our galaxy, the **Milky Way**.  Milky Way is a spiral galaxy and hence has four major spiral arms and a central buldge. The Sun (and, of course, the rest of our solar system) is located near the **Orion** arm, between two major arms (Perseus and Sagittarius).

**[image: Orion]**

Comment: I see 4 major spiral arms...

Comment: Thank you parth.Is the centre of galaxy a rigid body or space?

Comment: @dipendra neither. It is stars and gas and black holes and etc. Not a rigid body, and there is some space, but I wouldn't go so far as to say it is just space

Comment: As Kyle said, it is a single supermassive Black Hole.

Comment: @dipendra the supermassive black hole is only about 1% of the mass causing the Sun to orbit the center of the galaxy.  Other stars in the central part of the galaxy are the main source of mass.

Comment: how to accept,i dnt knw.Can u teach me?

Comment: There must be a tick on the top left of my answer, click that.