# If all motion stops, does time cease to exist? Is awareness then still possible in this stae?

Tags: thermodynamics, time, arrow-of-time

I mean on an entire universe level. We rotate the sun, the sun some black hole, the galaxy speeding off from some explosions in an unknown central location... On it goes. Everything moving at completely insane speeds and it occurs to me that if time relative to one moving extremely fast within these bubbles of extremely fast systems can be measurably "slowed" such as what we see on a satellite's clock, well what if that notion was expanded?

It occurred to me, and it's probably silly, but that this motion is what allows for the perception of time. Here's why. If speed slows time relative to those observers going slower, the same should hold true the opposite direction. And so if all motion at every level stopped, it would seem 100% logical all time would be a single infinite instant, well, that's zero time by definition.

If there is no time there is no order to things--like quantum physics with the goofy effect-before-cause observations. If a human brain could survive such universal catastrophe... Or inevitable conclusion to the universe maybe... Would the firing synapses that make sense of it all stop? Or instead simply have fired at all directions at that singular moment and so be both aware but also in stasis?

Comment: Sorry, this is out of topic for this site. It discusses mainstrem physics, not alternate scenaria.  try the https://scifi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hello. Please note that the answer to this question will be based on opinion. This forum deals with mainstream physics that are answered with scientific facts backed by evidence.

Comment: This is more a philosophy of time question than a physics question; see https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/time/#ReduPlatRespTime for how philosophers have treated the question.

Comment: *"We rotate the sun, the sun some black hole, the galaxy speeding off from some explosions in an unknown central location"*. Yes, Earth revolves around the Sun, but the Sun doesn't revolve around "some black hole", although there does happen to be a large black hole in the middle of our galaxy. And the galaxy is certainly *not* speeding off from some explosions.

Comment: @Drjh BTW, some people get rather upset when you refer to Stack Exchange sites as forums. There are some similarities, but several important differences. Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/334566 If new members didn't mistakenly treat our sites as forums there would be fewer problems...

Comment: @PM 2Ring. The solar system rotates around the center of the Miky Way just as the earth the sun. There is a black hole at the center of that.

Comment: Please see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/411003/123208 & https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/20614/16685

Answer (score 1):

Thermodynamics laws do apply to the 'everything stops' scenario,
in the sense that this is a description of absolute zero temperature.
The third law of thermodymics is that entropy is minimized at absolute zero (would
be a state of zero entropy, in an ordered crystal, for instance).

That minimum entropy, however, has a consequence; no time-direction
determination can occur without an increase in entropy (and if
entropy is zero, and stays zero, there's no increase).  This
does indicate that normal consciousness (with awareness of time)
would necessarily be impossible.

While motion requires time, time itself is unmeaningful without
entropy, in the thermodynamic sense.

If a synapse firing is a cause-before-effect sequence, it would also
be one of the things that just couldn't happen in that state.